# How to Call two class with loop and with different parameters in contruct symfony

Tags: symfony4

I have a loop to browse 2 class but the problem that it does not have the same signature
one takes in the constructor 2 input and the other takes a single input
how can I correct knowing that I'm forced to make a loop for

I really do not find a solution

this is my funcion  where I put loop for

```html
  */
    public function run()
    {
        if (is_null($this->input) || empty($this->input)) {
            throw new EmptyDataException("No data or empty data");
        }

        foreach ($this->extensions as $extension) {
            $extensionProcess = "App\\Analyser\\Extension\\" . $extension->getCategory() . "\\" . $extension->getName();
            $instance = new $extensionProcess($this->ruleManager, $this->analyseRuleManager);
            $instance->setAnalyse($this->analyse);
            $instance->input($this->input);
            $instance->run();
        }
    }
```

this is  class 1

```html
/**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param RuleManager $ruleManager
     * @param AnalyseRuleManager $analyseRuleManager
     */
    public function __construct(RuleManager $ruleManager,
                                AnalyseRuleManager $analyseRuleManager)
    {
        $this->ruleManager = $ruleManager;
        $this->analyseRuleManager = $analyseRuleManager;
    }
```

this is contruct 2

```html
/**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param AnalyseManager $analyseManager
     */
    public function __construct(AnalyseManager $analyseManager)
    {
        $this->analyseManager = $analyseManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a base problem with the Dependency Injection of Symfony, I recommend you to read step by step the documentation about the [service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html), it's a core feauture of Symfony(and other frameworks) and is very important.

If you define your extensions as service after you will not need to call the constructor. If you want to get one of this services depending of the value of extension I would create another service called AnalyserExtensionFactory that will look similiar to this:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);


namespace App\Analyser\Extension;

class AnalyserExtensionFactory
{
    public function __construct(Class1 $class1, Class2 $class2)
    {
        $this->class1 = $class1;
        $this->class2 = $class2;
    }

    public function getByExtension(Extension $extension) : ?ClassInterface
    {
        switch ($extension->getName()) {
            case 'class1':
                return $this->class1;
            case 'class2':
                return $this->class2;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And after use this factory in your `run()` function.

The ClassInterface should be implemented in your Class1 and Class2 (and have the methods `setAnalyse`, `input` and `run`)

Advanced tip: This factory could be done cleaner with [service tagging](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html)